# Error on using Mex with OpenCVLibrary in Matlab

Tags: c++, matlab, opencv, mex

I am using a program that is written with OpenCV on Matlab. The program has been compiled and a .mexw64 file was generated.

I have added my OpenCV library to Matlab using mexopts.bat and the compile was successful.

When I call the function of the program, an error is generated:

`Invalid MEX-file 'test.mexw64': test.mexw64 is not a valid Win32 application.`

Comment: Is your .mexw64 extension linked to a runnable executer?  Thats the sort of message you get when the OS doesn't know what to use to run the file.

Comment: It looks like you're trying to run a 64-bit mex file with a 32-bit version of Matlab. What does `mexext` return? That won't work. I assume the mex file was compiled on a different computer?

Comment: @horchler The [mexext] returns [mexw64]

Comment: @Brody May I know how to link the .mexw64 to a runnable executer? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the directory containing your mexw64 file is included in the MATLAB path.